# Syntax error, '>' expected MVC razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

For some reason my code works fine, but there seems to be a syntax error when i use

```
@model List<ObjectClass>
```

However, the code runs fine.

I could just create a wrapper class but i just wanted to get input on why this is happening?

EDIT: Visual Studio 2013

Comment: I recently had similar problem, but I had `@Model List<Person>`. Notice capital "M". In your case everything looks fine. Just restart VS.

Comment: Yep that fixed it... that's annoying lol

Comment: answer posted, upvotes welcome -))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had similar problem, but I had @Model List. Notice capital "M". In your case everything looks fine. Just restart VS.